# Analytics event tracking issue

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick, event-tracking

I'm event tracking read more events on category pages. Every category page has an intro text. Some category pages has long text, so a small part is vissible to read. To show the complete intro there is an 'read more' button.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-readmore" onclick="eventTracking();">Read more</a>
```

When the user clicks on the readmore link the function eventTracking() is called

```
function eventTracking(){
        // values are in this example hardcoded
        // the values are readed from a hidden div on the page.
        // this div has data attributes with the values changed
        // by php for different category pages

        var hittype         = "event";
        var eventcategory   = "Link";
        var eventaction     = "Read more";,
        var eventlabel      = "Clicked on test category";

    if(hittype && eventcategory && eventaction && eventlabel){
        ga("send", {
            hitType: hittype,
            eventCategory: eventcategory,
            eventAction: eventaction,
            eventLabel: eventlabel
        });
    }
}
```

This works fine. When i go to a category page that has an readmore link and i click on readmore, the results are send to Analytics.

But in a strange way the Analytics results also contains data of category pages that has no readmore link.

How could this magically happen?

It only fires on 'onclick' and not al pages does have this link. 
Is the if check not correct? Or could something else causes this weird behaviour?

Comment: Which report(s) are you specifically referring to? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: In analytics it is in events then overview. There is Some data that could not be triggered by the onclick